# Error using scipy.io.wavfile

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having some troubles using the function read from scipy.io.wavfile.

My attempt:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs, data = read('A.wav')
```

This this the error message:

[image]

The file A.wav is in the same directory as the .py file
What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that file is a .wav? You could share that file.

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check by running `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @eyllanesc how can I share the file?

Comment: @Dirac 
upload it to drive, dropbox, etc and share the link.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser 1.0.0 version. Should it be updated?

Comment: @eyllanesc https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kksHwOeUju8KxIgZfUQqiZv7Rp17Y34v

Comment: @Dirac, no, updating won't help.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), your file "A.wav" uses the codec "PCM MU-LAW (mlaw)".  The scipy library can't read WAV files in that format (and neither can Python's standard library `wave`).  To use scipy, you'll have to use another tool to convert the file to PCM or IEEE floating point [*].  For example, I used VLC to convert the file to "Audio - CD" format, and I was able to read the new file with scipy.

[*]  Technical details that you probably don't need to see: those formats correspond to `wFormatTag` value `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM = 0x0001` or `wFormatTag` value `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT = 0x0003`, respectively, in the format chunk of the WAV file.